# Integrate 3rd party 3d renderer in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qml

I have been looking for ways to render a 3d scene using Qt QML controls. I saw there is a framebuffer example which uses `Canvas3D` control to get OpenGL 3d scene rendered. However this example uses JavaScript for the rendering logic.

I was looking for a way to do the same but via a C++ class. Is there any way to do so? Or any example available?

Ideally, I would like to use 3rd party renderer to create a scene. Any ideas?

Comment: There are no "Qt QML" controls in Qt. There are "Qt Quick" controls, which are C++. You may render any QML scene to any GL context. Or you may use QtQuick GL context to draw your content.

Comment: Can you please share any example?

Comment: ofc I can, but they are too complex, to post them as answer. You may use google.